# Wordpress: get subtitle

Tags: php, wordpress

I have here a loop to get the parent pages titles and featured images. I want to add the subtitle, but the subtitle is not displayed. In other templates I use  to get the subtitle of the specific page. But here in the loop I need the subtitles of the parent pages.
 I use for the subtitle a plugin wp_subtitle: here is a [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subtitle/)

here is the code snippet:

```
 <?php 
  $args = array(
      'parent' => $post->ID,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
  ); 
  $pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
  <div style="max-width:1240px;"> 
  <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
   <div class="box">
      <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
      <span class="title"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></span>
      <span class="thumbnail"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?></span>
      <span class="subtitle"><?php echo $page->the_subtitle; ?></span>
      <span class="desc"><?php echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'desc', true); ?></span>
      </a>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function provided by the plugin, `get_the_subtitle()`:

```
...
<span class="subtitle"><?php echo get_the_subtitle($page); ?></span>
...
```